# How to ensure that text is rendered to fit in tree?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

`JTree` does not seem to automatically resize its nodes to accommodate fonts of size `20+`. I've tried calling `revalidate()`, but that doesn't seem to help. The text in the nodes appears "squished" vertically so that the top and bottom of letters are clipped.

How can I use large fonts and ensure that they are displayed properly with a `JTree`?

Comment: try `treeGuy.setLargeModel(true);`

Comment: might depend on LAF: some (like win) set a fixed rowHeight - make sure you set it to -1 (or similar, don't quite remember) to force a variable rowHeight (which will query the renderer's size requirements)

Comment: These comments look suspiciously like answers... though the `setLargeModel(true)` approach did not have any effect on Mac OS X...

Comment: @kleopatra: Excellent! For reference, the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html#setRowHeight%28int%29) says " less than or equal to zero."

Comment: @trashgod thanks for the link, will try to remember :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some LAFs (e.g. WindowsLookAndFeel) set a fixed rowHeight which is rather arbitrary (like `16px`). Be sure either to force the tree to dynamically compute the height for each node:

```
 tree.setRowHeight(-1);
```

or calculate the rowHeight based on the tree's font and set that as the fixed height.

Comment: @Greg Mattes - sorry for the partial rollback, but code tag is for inline code, not for highlighting keywords :-) Thanks for correcting the typo!