# How to resize TreeCellEditor after it is displayed

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I have a `JTree` with a `TreeCellEditor` that has variable size (when you choose a value in one component within the editor, additional components are displayed). When the editor is shown initially, it is the correct size. However, if additional components are displayed that cause its preferred size to be larger, the editor will not be enlarged and its contents will be clipped.

I've found that if I set the size of the editor that it will resize, but I would like a way to have it automatically be resized when its preferred size changes.

Here's an example using a `JTextField` to simulate my editor. Clicking the button makes the text field preferred size larger, but in my editor this would be triggered from within the editor component and I don't want to explicitly set the size there as it's used in contexts other than as a tree cell editor.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTree;

public class Test extends JFrame {
    @Override
    public void setVisible(boolean b) {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JTree tree = new JTree();
        tree.setEditable(true);
        final JTextField field = new JTextField();
        tree.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(field));

        JButton button = new JButton(new AbstractAction("Make CellEditor Wider") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Dimension size = field.getPreferredSize();
                size.width += 50;
                field.setPreferredSize(size);
                field.setSize(size); // This forces the tree to show the correct size
            }
        });

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(tree, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setSize(500, 500);
        super.setVisible(b);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I recently learned about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19225982/230513).

Comment: Thanks, @trashgod. That works for row height. I'm interested here in cell editor width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, a tree (or more precisely: its ui-delegate) can handle editor components that have different sizes than the renderer component at the same node, though they assume that the size doesn't change during the lifetime of a single node editing process. The ui

- sizes/positions the editor component when starting the edit
- triggers an update of the node locations below the editor component (if needed)

For changes during the lifetime of an editor, a custom controller has to listen to those changes (and/or whatever triggers those) and then both tasks. Below is a textField with a prefSize depending on its content and a controller that listens to documentChanges and acts as needed.

```
// both height and width depend on content
final JTextField field = new JTextField() {

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        Dimension dim = super.getPreferredSize();
        int length = getText().length();
        dim.width += length * 10;
        dim.height += length * 2;
        return dim;
    }

};
// controller listens to changes to dynamically takes over the ui's job 
DocumentListener l = new DocumentListener() {

    protected void validateEditor(final JTextField field) {
        // the selectionModel's rowMapper is-a AbstractLayoutCache
        // BEWARE: implementation detail!
        TreeSelectionModel model = tree.getSelectionModel();
        // invalidate all cached node sizes/locations
        ((AbstractLayoutCache) model.getRowMapper()).invalidateSizes();
        // just a fancy cover method for revalidate/repaint
        tree.treeDidChange();
        // manually set the component's size
        field.setSize(field.getPreferredSize());
    }
    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        validateEditor(field);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        validateEditor(field);
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    }

};
field.getDocument().addDocumentListener(l);
```

Comment: Thanks @kleopatra. Since the tree assumes the size won't change, it sounds like there's no way to trigger a size change without actually changing the size of the editor yourself. If the editor component were contained in something with a layout manager, revalidating that container would cause the editor component to change size but since the tree isn't using a layout manager this won't happen.

Comment: @RangiKeen exactly :-)